# troubleshooting packet loss

Tags: router, packet-loss

I know this is a question with maybe too many possible answers, therefore i'm trying to reduce the number of path to explore. From what i've read so far, packet loss can be caused by

1. hardware performance (routers, switch,..)
2. link congestion
3. faulty cabling
4. software bugs.
   My situation is : i have 2 machines (MAC Os X and Windows 10) that undergo packet loss while **others don't**. I mean machines from the same building, on the same floor don't suffer from that issue.
    When i ping the router from those two, lots of packet are lost (about 60 percent). I don't think it's a software bug, link congestion or a hardware issue, otherwise other machines would suffer packet loss, wouldn't they? My guess is, it might come from the cabling. Waiting for the one specialized in wiring (in order to find how the cables are connected to the router), i'm asking you guys if someone can propose other leads? Any other causes?

Comment: Questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here, but you can ask those types of questions on [su].

Comment: it is not about "home networking", i had this situation in my company. 2 machines out of 200 were experiencing packet loss, and i had to determine  wether it was hardware or software related while waiting for the expert in cable connection.

Comment: i'm new in the IT service and there were too many cables and i couldn't determine how they were connected to the router (which port on which switch), the "cable guy" (that's how i call the one specialized in wiring in my company) showed me. Then testing different ports on the switch we  determined that the one used previously was "dead"

Comment: i asked this question because i wanted to be sure to explore every leads, like i said i'm new in my team and i have to prove my effectiveness

Comment: Sorry, but based on the wording, it sounded like a home networking question (too many of those lately). It has been my experience that when people think a switch port is dead, it really is a cable problem. Depending on the switch model, many switches (Cisco, for sure) use ASICs which control multiple switch ports, so you would normally end up with multiple dead switch ports instead of just one. There is the situation where someone messed up the pins inside the switch port, but I have fixed that with tine needle-nosed pliers, moving a pin the was knocked out of place.

Comment: My bad about the wording and thank you for the tip, i will check the pins inside the switch port.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to verify is that the speed/duplex settings on those systems match the switch configuration. You can also rule out any network/cable issues my taking a laptop and connecting it to the cable where one of those bad systems terminate. If the packet loss goes away it has something to do with the system not responding to ICMP packets. You can verify this by doing a file transfer to the system to determine if it reflects any problem. With 60% packet loss if it is a hard network problem that system will be not be usable from the standpoint of any other application traffic.

Comment: Solved! it was because of a corrupted port on the switch, but thank you for what you proposed